# Can I submit two papers to the same conference event as me the first author?

Tags: publications, conference, authorship

I have two studies that are not related to each other but in the same domain (Social Media Analysis) and I already submitted one of them to a conference as my name the main author.

-Can I submit the second paper where I am also the main author to the same conference event? I have read the conferance regulation but did not find any related information for such an issue.

EDIT: I also tried to contact them, but since two weeks, still no answer and the deadline is within 2 days. And normally if it ok to submit two papers, will I be having two-time slot for the presentation, or will it be one slot to manage both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many conferences (though, I don't know if it is the norm in your discipline), it is common to submit two papers as a first author/presenter, unless the conference states that it prohibits this. In your case, it does not. When you state that you are the "main" author, there is a difference if you are the sole author or the first author. Some conferences do not want someone to submit multiple papers as a presenter, because it can create difficulties in scheduling the sessions. In these cases, they may allow multiple submissions as a first author as long as it indicates that a different person is presenting each paper.

Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

**Yes,** unless the conference regulation specifies a different policy, it's fully OK to submit multiple papers as main author to the same conference.

Comment: and will I be able to have two separate time slot in the presentation to present them? or will it be on slot where I have to manage both papers?

Comment: Normally, the conference organizers should notice and won't schedule your talks inside the same time slot. To be on the safe side, I would send them an e-mail in case both submissions are accepted.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't found anything in the conference regulations, the best solution is to contact the organizers directly and ask.

Since nothing is specified against it directly, you can *try* and submit two papers. However, keep in mind that they may nonetheless decide to disqualify the second submission (for example, if they simply did not think to add this rule to the submission guidelines, which can happen).

Comment: I think this is a poor answer. If it doesn't prohibit, which is EXTREMELY rare in any case, it is a fair assumption it is permitted. If it is prohibited it should be stated in the call.